# progress dialog with async task issues

Tags: android, asynchronous, dialog, progress

what I am trying to do is use async task to display a progress dialog while my app searches for their location. after their location is found it should show an alert dialog with some info. however i am not 100% sure how to do this. this is what i have in LocationChanged.java:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground( Void... params ) {
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            lat =location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
            //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            try{
                addresses=(geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1));
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    // String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                    String id = city.substring(0,city.length()-5);
                    String state1=String.valueOf(id.charAt(id.length()-3));
                    String state2=String.valueOf(id.charAt(id.length()-2));
                    STATE = state1+state2;
                    //String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                    //tv.setText(STATE);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                }
                else {
                    //tv.setText("Oops...");
                }

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

and this is the logcat when it runs:

```
07-08 17:26:21.456: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2755): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:209)
    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:209)
    at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:687)
    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:512)
    at com.nick.whatsthetip.LocationChanged.doInBackground(LocationChanged.java:121)
    at com.nick.whatsthetip.LocationChanged.doInBackground(LocationChanged.java:24)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 5 more
07-08 17:26:21.716: ERROR/EmbeddedLogger(696): App crashed! Process:    com.nick.whatsthetip
07-08 17:26:21.716: ERROR/EmbeddedLogger(696): App crashed! Package: com.nick.whatsthetip v5 (1.1.0)
07-08 17:26:21.987: ERROR/WindowManager(2755): Activity com.nick.whatsthetip.Settings    has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41075198 that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.nick.whatsthetip.Settings has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41075198 that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:468)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:419)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
    at com.nick.whatsthetip.LocationChanged.onPreExecute(LocationChanged.java:49)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
    at com.nick.whatsthetip.Settings$3.onClick(Settings.java:119)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
```

Answer (score 2):

You you should know that, doInBackground method of an AsyncTask is executed on a "Worker" Thread, only onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are executed over the main thread, hence, trying to modify anything related to UI (like a progress dialog...) from doInBackground will cause an exception, what you have to do is make sure that any code modifying the UI is being called from main thread and not from a Worker Thread...

Regards

Comment: ok so is it not possible to update the ui elements from that class, does it have to be done from where the original class where i call the class containing the async task?

Comment: Is not the class it self, is the doInBackground method, that method is meant to not block the main thread, in other words is a worker thread, so you can use onPostExecuted method of AsyncTask to dismiss dialog once whatever you are doing in doInBackground is done...

Answer (score 1):

This training lesson: [Displaying a Location Address](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) shows you how to run an AsyncTask to reverse geocode a location.

It's not necessary to respond to the location updates in the background. I suggest you take onLocationChanged out of doInBackground and add it as a method in the UI thread. It's asynchronous, so it won't cause an ANR. When you get a location, *then* execute the background task that finds the city, state, etc. The training lesson shows you how to put up a progress indicator without having to use a dialog.

Comment: ok ill keep working with that sample. this is turning out to be alot harder than i originally had thought. thanks